# Rails 3 question with Sanitize Gem features

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sanitize

I'm a relative rails newbie and have a question about the sanitize gem. It is easy to install and use, but for some reason when I choose to have my own elements array, it isn't working. It is still sanitizing the elements I'm trying to approve. Here's my code:

```
def scrub(html)  
 # Setup whitelist of html elements that are allowed.
 allowed_elements = ['b', 'blockquote', 'em', 'i', 'li', 'ol', 'p', 'pre', 'u', 'ul']
 Sanitize.clean(html, :elements => allowed_elements)
end
```

but it is showing the following as a result:

```
<p> And Some Content... &lt;script&gt;mal&lt;/script&gt; 
and <em>italics and bold</em></p> 
<ol> <li> list</li> <li> list</li> </ol>
<blockquote> <p> blockquote</p> </blockquote> 
<ul> <li> bullet</li> <li> bullet</li> </ul>
```

thanks for any pointers about why this simple format isn't working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def scrub(html)  
 # Setup whitelist of html elements that are allowed.
 allowed_elements = ['b', 'blockquote', 'em', 'i', 'li', 'ol', 'p', 'pre', 'u', 'ul']
 Sanitize.clean(html, :elements => allowed_elements).html_safe
end
```

Comment: But it is escaping them. It is actually showing the tags rather than rendering them. Am I misunderstanding? I thought "allowed_elements" would be those tags allowed to be sent to the view. Is the issue then, that the view isn't actually rendering the content as HTML? I"d like to see an ordered list, paragraphs, italics, bold, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: Ah, the escaping is done by Rails 3 as a security measure, because Sanitize.clean isn't returning the contents as html_safe. I've updated the answer to reflect the changes.